# Implementing custom repeat until structure

Tags: scala

My assignment was to write a custom repeat structure that could be used like this:

```
var i = 0
repeat {
    i = i + 1
}(i > 5)
```

Initially, I had the following code:

```
trait RepeatUntil {
  def repeat(f: => Unit)(condition: => Boolean): Unit = {
    if (!condition) {
      f
      repeat(f)(condition)
    }
  }
}
```

However, while running all the tests (that aren't visible to me as a student), there was one test that just didn't succeed. After just fooling around with my code, I got a working trait. I just can't understand why my code down does work, and my initial code didn't work. Don't they do exactly the same?

```
trait RepeatUntil {
  def repeat(f: => Unit) (condition: => Boolean): Unit = {
    val result = f
    if(condition) result else repeat(f)(condition)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial code, you test the `condition` *before* executing the code within the braces. In your corrected code, you test the `condition` *after* executing the code within the braces. This will make a big difference, and I'm surprised that only one test failed! (Maybe the online grading program stops when it gets to the first test that fails.)